# how to parse Excel worksheet/table and map excel columns to a data entity in Dynamics 365 Operations

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

what actions/connectors one could use  to parse a excel file and map columuns from a excel table to and external store, in this case i wish to make a record in Dynamics 365 operations using OData entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are the obvious RapidStart Services no option for you? 
If you definitely need to use OData, I suggest building a publishable OData page via WebServices. You then can implement a parser in any environment/language you prefer and submit the new record via a RESTful Webservice-Call (which nearly every framework should allow) to this very same page, in order to submit the record to your productive environment.

Comment: well. it is my first week working with logic apps. didn't find enough information on the topic on internet so decided to ask here.